# Logstash to add new non existing nested field in all query matching documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, pipeline, logstash-configuration

I am using ELK 7.12.

My external json :

```
{"req-id":"Test9","process-code":"demo9","field1":1,"field2":"abc"}
```

Elasticsearch document:

```
{"docid":"...", "h":{...},"a":{...}}
```

Intended output:

```
{"docid":"...", "h":{...},"a":{...}, "externaldata":{"field1":1,"field2":"abc"}}
```

Logstash pipeline :

```
filter {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
        user => elastic
        password => elastic
        index => "demo7"
        query => "h.req-id:%{[req-id]} AND h.process-code:%{[process-code]}"
        docinfo_fields => {
          "_id" => "docid"
        }
    }
    if ("_elasticsearch_lookup_failure" not in [tags]) {
        mutate {
            add_field => {"externaldata"=>{}}
            add_field => { "externaldatafield1" => "%{[field1]}" }
            add_field => { "externaldatafield2" => "%{[field2]}" }
        }
        mutate {
            rename => {
                "externaldatafield1" => "[externaldata][field1]"
                "externaldatafield2" => "[externaldata][field2]"
            }
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
        user => elastic
        password => elastic
        index => "demo7"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        document_id => "%{docid}"
    }
}
```

Error :

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [externaldata] of type [text] in document with id '901'. Preview of field's value: '{field1=1, field2=abcd}'"
```

I have tried few combinations from other SO posts to add nested field in event but pipeline failed to execute. Please provide me right syntax. My study reference is [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field).

**Edit 1:**

As per comment from leandrojmp, result of `GET /demo7/_mapping` is :

```
"externaldata" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
```

After studying mappings concept, I deleted index and re-executed pipeline successfully.

Now issue is, only one of the 2 query matching documents is updated.
How to update all query matching documents with `externaldata` field? Please provide reference if I should use any loop/jump code ?

**Edit 2:**

My original question about additional field and mapping error is solved by leandrojmp; hence accepting their answer. But multi-doc update issue still exists. So far, I understood that instead of "elasticsearch", we should use "http" or "exec" plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you already have a document in your index where the field `externaldata` has the type `text` and now you are trying to index the same field as an `object`.

For example if in one document you have `externaldata` as a text:

```
{ 
    "externaldata": "some string text value" 
}
```

And in other document you have `externaldata` as and object:

```
{ 
    "externaldata": {
        "field1": "1",
        "field2": "2"
    }
}
```

One of these two documents will be rejected, which one will depends on your mapping, if you do not explicitly applied a mapping, elasticsearch will create a map for the field with the type it receives first, which in your case seems to be the `text` type.

To solve this you need to delete your index and apply a [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/explicit-mapping.html) for the field `externaldata` or index a document where this field is an object.

The mapping would be something like this:

```
{
    "externaldata": {
        "properties: {
            "field1": { "type": "keyword" },
            "field2": { "type": "keyword" }
        }
    }   
}
```

If in your data you have documents where this field is not an object, you will need to change its name, you can't have the same field as an string and as an object.

Also, your mutate filter is wrong, you just need something like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[externaldata][field1]" => "%{[field1]}" }
    add_field => { "[externaldata][field2]" => "%{[field2]}" }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all details. I dont have "externaldata" field anywhere - neither in elasticsearch doc nor in external json. I want to create it while inserting 2 new fields from external json to matching ES docs. Yes, I tried your combination but getting same error.

Comment: The mapping error will exists when you try to index a field with a different mapping type, the field `externaldata` in your index is mapped as `text`, for this to happen it was indexed like this before or it has an explicit mapping applied. Run `GET /demo7/_mapping` in Kibana Dev tools and update your question with the result of the mapping for the field `externaldata`.

Comment: Thanks leandrojmp about mapping comment, its new concept for me. Please check my Edit 1 section and suggest me way to update all query satisfying document. I executed same pipeline again and again but nothing happened. It updates only 1 doc always :(